# Get train data generator and save them

Tags: python, save, conv-neural-network, generator

I am developing a faster RCNN algorithm. I have a function get_anchor_gt that Generate the ground_truth anchors.I call the function in the following code

```
# Get train data generator which generate X, Y, image_data
data_gen_train = get_anchor_gt(train_imgs, C, get_img_output_length, mode='train')
```

When I execute the following code

```
X, Y, image_data, debug_img, debug_num_pos = next(data_gen_train)
```

it start to train and its saving in the jupyter notebook and the size grows up to 200 mbs and the notebook crush.Is there a way I can save then somewhere like in the harddisk and later load them?

This is get_anchor_gt

```
#Generate the ground_truth anchors

def get_anchor_gt(all_img_data, C, img_length_calc_function, mode='train'):
""" Yield the ground-truth anchors as Y (labels)

Args:
    all_img_data: list(filepath, width, height, list(bboxes))
    C: config
    img_length_calc_function: function to calculate final layer's feature map (of base model) size according to input image size
    mode: 'train' or 'test'; 'train' mode need augmentation

Returns:
    x_img: image data after resized and scaling (smallest size = 300px)
    Y: [y_rpn_cls, y_rpn_regr]
    img_data_aug: augmented image data (original image with augmentation)
    debug_img: show image for debug
    num_pos: show number of positive anchors for debug
"""
while True:

    for img_data in all_img_data:
        try:

            # read in image, and optionally add augmentation

            if mode == 'train':
                img_data_aug, x_img = augment(img_data, C, augment=True)
            else:
                img_data_aug, x_img = augment(img_data, C, augment=False)

            (width, height) = (img_data_aug['width'], img_data_aug['height'])
            (rows, cols, _) = x_img.shape

            assert cols == width
            assert rows == height

            # get image dimensions for resizing
            (resized_width, resized_height) = get_new_img_size(width, height, C.im_size)

            # resize the image so that smalles side is length = 300px
            x_img = cv2.resize(x_img, (resized_width, resized_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            debug_img = x_img.copy()

            try:
                y_rpn_cls, y_rpn_regr, num_pos = calc_rpn(C, img_data_aug, width, height, resized_width, resized_height, img_length_calc_function)
            except:
                continue

            # Zero-center by mean pixel, and preprocess image

            x_img = x_img[:,:, (2, 1, 0)]  # BGR -> RGB
            x_img = x_img.astype(np.float32)
            x_img[:, :, 0] -= C.img_channel_mean[0]
            x_img[:, :, 1] -= C.img_channel_mean[1]
            x_img[:, :, 2] -= C.img_channel_mean[2]
            x_img /= C.img_scaling_factor

            x_img = np.transpose(x_img, (2, 0, 1))
            x_img = np.expand_dims(x_img, axis=0)

            y_rpn_regr[:, y_rpn_regr.shape[1]//2:, :, :] *= C.std_scaling

            x_img = np.transpose(x_img, (0, 2, 3, 1))
            y_rpn_cls = np.transpose(y_rpn_cls, (0, 2, 3, 1))
            y_rpn_regr = np.transpose(y_rpn_regr, (0, 2, 3, 1))

            yield np.copy(x_img), [np.copy(y_rpn_cls), np.copy(y_rpn_regr)], img_data_aug, debug_img, num_pos

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
```

Comment: Hi, from your code I cannot completely understand the context in which you are operating: which libraries you are importing and using, where the function `get_anchor_gt` comes from... Please provide more info

Comment: Hi Piertoni I added the code for 'get_anchor_gt'. Hope you have more information to solve this

Comment: Just trying to give some hints: 1) 200mb of ram is not so much, try to execute outside of jupyter in a normal python environment 2) You can remove `debug_img` creation to consume less ram.
3) from what you say seems that when you execute the instruction `... next(data_gen_train)` is never returning? Seems a bit weird...

Comment: I executed a normal python script it displayed a blank terminal and didn't get result after Soo many hours. step 1 didn't work.2 I removed debug_img and still getting blank terminal. What could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I think it is silently failing at:

```py
try:
    y_rpn_cls, y_rpn_regr, num_pos = calc_rpn(C, img_data_aug, width, height, resized_width, resized_height, img_length_calc_function)
except:
    continue
```

You did not put anything to be informed about an exception, so if this line fails
(and for whatever reason, even a typo or a wrong number of arguments) you will
never seen what does happen and the script will continue running the for loop.

At first you can just remove the `try/except` and see explicitly what is the problem,
with that information you can go on debugging.

Some more hints:

1. Dont use `try/except`, but instead:

```py
try:
    # ..code
except Exception as exc:
    # something went wrong, at least print the exception
    print(exc)
```

2. python has a debugger called `pdb` you can start debugging a program
   going line by line and checking variable values.
   Start with `python -m pdb yourprogram.py` and go on debugging.
   You should study a bit `pdb` commands in order to do this, but this
   will be useful now on, check [Tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/) and [Official Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Comment: It can run when you when you comment on the try. When I run pdb and reach to the the 'X, Y, image_data, debug_img, debug_num_pos = next(data_gen_train)' it shows a blank terminal. What could be the problem